# Why is my TYPO3 Symfony command able to add new objects to repositories but not update existing ones depending on the project instance?

Tags: symfony, command, typo3, typo3-10.x, ddd-repositories

the question does indeed seem a bit odd, but let me explain.
Also I'm not sure about some of the tags of this question.

We have a TYPO3 10 project in which we are using EXT:news as means to manage and display events. The `News` model has already been extended by some other extension, which adds properties that define a start as well as an end day and time. Only recently we started or rather wanted to start using EXT:calendarize and EXT:calendarize_news to be able to display those events in an interactive calendar. To save the need to manually manage EXT:calendarize `Configuration`s for each `News` object I decided to implement a schedulable Symfony command to do that.

For both steps `add`ing a new `Configuration` object to the database, and `update`ing the `News` object with the new configuration, I decided to go with the respective repository's functions and calling `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager`'s `persistAll()` after each one. Each repository and the persistance manager are fetched by an `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager` instance.

The problem we do not understand:
The new `Configuration` objects get properly persisted, but the updates to any `News` object may or may not work depending on the system we're running the command on

- local development environment: no issues, everything works as intended (docker-setup)
- staging environment: works after flushing the cache (currently not able to reproduce)
- production environment: does not work at all.

What I mean by "does not work" is that even though each `News` object's `_isDirty()`-check returns `TRUE` after assigning (`ObjectStorage::add`) the generated `Configuration` object, the assignment does not get persisted leaving the database field `NULL` instead of the expected UID of the generated `Configuration` object

At this point, Ive debugged a little and the `PersistenceManager` correctly stores the changed `News` objects within its `$changedObjects` property and upon `persistAll()` removes them from there as it just creates a new `ObjectStorage`, and I'm not sure debugging into `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Backend::persistObject` will be of much help.

The problem does not seem to be code related, because it works on three instances (2x Develop, Staging) but not on the third (Production) which in itself seems oddly specific to us. Staging and Production share the same server.

What we've tried so far:

- verified the same php version (local <-> server)
- verified the same MySQL version (local <-> server)
- verified the spl_object_id of the `PersistenceManager` (EXT:news `NewsRepository`, EXT:calendarize `ConfigurationRepository` and the one gotten from the `ObjectManager`) (all three)
- executing the command via CLI and scheduler BE module (all three)
- using the same TYPO3_CONTEXT (Production) locally and on staging, thus using the same TYPO3 configs, to try and reproduce the issue in a more debuggable environment (to no avail)(local, staging)
- verified each `News` object is dirty after assigning the corresponding persisted `Configuration` object (all three)
- checked any logs for potential errors (none found) (all three)
- testing on another development machine (successful)

I also tested stepping away from the `NewsRepository::update()` and using a `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Connection`  object which in turn executes a MySQL-query. This approach does indeed work.

Still, we'd like to understand the issue with the repository approach. Any clues, hints or thoughts on why this may or may not work are appreciated.

If you need more information on anything, please, feel free to ask.

Reminder: From our understanding the issue is **not** "Hey, this generally does not work", because it does on at least three completely independent systems. It's more of a "It does work, but not on Production and we couldn't figure out, why that's the case.".

After reading this again I'm not sure if some of the used tags really fit the question, but I'll leave them for now.

Best regards

Lukas

Comment: Just a guess: Production probably has a bit more access to the database. Could it be that the news table is not writable/locked in time because blocked by other accesses? Or in another way a performance impact? Have you tried it at quieter times?

Comment: @JulianHofmann Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I tried quieter times by scheduling the command to be run at 0100 local time. Sadly this didn't work out, either.

Comment: If the DB is locked, should we be able to get some error message from somewhere? How?